# Keras script stops running temporarily

Tags: python, keras

I am using a Keras model to calculate Shapley values so I need to make a lot of predictions. After some time, let's say 15 minutes, the script just stops running. The progress bar doesn't update and I can see that the GPU is not used as before. The script doesn't fail or something. If I come back after a few hours, switch on the screen and clicks on the prompt it starts working again.

I'm running the python script in an anaconda prompt. For the predictions I just use model.predict_on_batch(). I have switched off the sleep mode of my desktop. Running on Windows 11, python 3.9 and keras 2.10.0

What can I do so that the script keeps running?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out automatic switching off the screen leads to the script to stop. Not really what I expected